# Best push service option for React Native Android/IOS?

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I have been following many projects which demonstrate the push service.
But there are many problems specially when the app is closed/kill (IOS too).

My first preference would be using FCM with react-native and followed [This project on git](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues). But it too have issues with notifications.

Is there any full proof source showing the push with android/IOS even when closed/kill?Anything is deeply appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried Firebase Notification:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/

```
- Easy Implementation
- Works really well
- No inbox messaging (as far as i saw - correct me if I am wrong)
```

At the moment I am using Urban Airship. Wich is not free to use but has a larger SDK to use.

https://www.urbanairship.com/products/mobile-app-engagement/pricing

```
- Also has Inbox messaging
- Deep Linking
```

Both are working fine if the app is closed.

Comment: If you have more details or better information about the provider - just tell me and i can add some important informations. But best would be to look on the specific website and read the docs

Comment: Did you use react-native for this?

Comment: Yes I used React Native but had to implement the Notification Service Natively (Android/iOS). Wich wasn't that hard and you find really good manuals:

Example manual: https://medium.com/@tewolfe2/push-notifications-with-react-native-ios-and-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-6492b7326b53#.2gmlnc8bj

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Will get back to you if I face any problems :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a pretty long chapter in my book on Android push messaging. Here is the flowchart I present on choosing a technology:

[image]

You should be able to get a good implemention using GCM/FCM with respect to power off and app close, but the bottom line is, GCM/FCM does not provide quaranteed delivery Quality of Serivce. They also will not quarantee order of message delivery. If you use MQTT, you can get this by setting QOS mode = 2.

MQTT is not hard to implement for Android. You can use the open source Mosquitto broker on the server side. It only take me 15 minutes to set this up on AWS or any unix server.

In your Android app, you then implement your own long lived service, and the Paho Android library is very stable and supports the 3 QoS levels, including QoS=2 which is the guananteed delievery mode.

Anyway, something else to think about. I use MQTT a lot. FCM is great, and it even supports topic messaging now, which is how the MQTT pub/sub model works. You just will never get guanarteed delivery QoS level with FCM.